# Chrome doesn't display VMware Workstation online help

Tags: google-chrome, vmware-workstation

VMware Workstation implements West Wind HTML Help Builder for it's help menus and my default browser is Chrome. When I click on Help > Help Topics Chrome only displays two blank frames with no content. This is the address in the awesome bar:

```
file:///C:/Program%20Files/VMware/VMware%20Workstation/help/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm
```

My installation of Chrome does this with all programs that use wwhelp. Can anyone help me troubleshoot this behavior?
Versions:
Google Chrome 9.0.597.94
VMware Workstation 7.1.3 build-324285